# Insert data to column which has two relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, relationship, erd

So, what I want to do in here is I want to insert the data to table1 who has 'username' field, and this 'username' field has two relationships, which is go to student table and teacher table. But, when I insert the data to user table, I have a problem, and the problem caused by this 'username' field. It caused because the data of 'username' field is not the same as a unique key in student table, and when I change it and made the data same, I get an error too, but this time the data is not the same as a unique in teacher table. So, is it possible to make this 'username' field just get one of the table, like if one of student table and teacher table's data is in 'username', it still can be used. Or maybe this is wrong because of bad ERD? Here's my ERD, if you're asking it:

[image]

And well, I know this is really, really bad idea but I made the name in teacher table and student table become a unique key, because I can't create foreign key if I didn't do that. Please, I'm really thankful to your answer.

Here's the ddl for that 3 tables :

Student table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[student](
[studentid] [int] IDENTITY(2016000001,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[address] [text] NOT NULL,
[gender] [varchar](7) NOT NULL,
[dateofbirth] [date] NOT NULL,
[nohp] [varchar](13) NOT NULL,


CONSTRAINT [PK_student] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[studentid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],


CONSTRAINT [IX_student] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
[name] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Teacher Table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[teacher](
[teacherid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[gender] [varchar](7) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_teacher] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 

(
    [teacherid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_teacher] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [name] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

User table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user](
[userid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[username] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[password] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[role] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_user] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [userid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[user]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_user_student] FOREIGN KEY([username])
REFERENCES [dbo].[student] ([name])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[user] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_user_student]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[user]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_user_teacher] FOREIGN KEY([username])
REFERENCES [dbo].[teacher] ([name])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[user] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_user_teacher]
GO
```

Comment: Why not just create a column in both `teacher` and `student` which is a `foreign key` to the `userid` field in the `user` table, then you can use a `JOIN` to get the `username` of a student or teacher by joining on the `user` table.

Comment: You can't create a foreign key?  They keys you're using should be unique.  In this sense, like @RyanWilson said, you should create another column for [UserID] and use that as your foreign key.  Also...Student -> Users is 1-to-many?

Comment: Yeah, I think about that too, because unique key in the name? Nah. Maybe I will made new username columns in both student and teachers too. But, the real issue here is I can't insert the username. It said like error because the data is not in the unique key, but actually there is a data in unique key. Like, I insert the username that same as the name in the student table, but I can't do that because the data is not the same as teacher table. The same thing happen when I input the data that is in teacher table.

Comment: @PreQL I already made the unique key, but the unique key is in the name field. Well, that is not the problem for now, I can actually just made the new column for that one. But, the insert is the only thing I really am fighting. I can made a foreign key.

Comment: Using names as keys is really bad, but I see several other issues with your design here. What would be far more helpful than a picture of your design it if you could post the actual ddl (create table statements).

Comment: In that design I think that the user table should be the leading one. To that table should refer the student and teacher tables and not as it is in the diagram as these tables are the leading ones.

Comment: However username you may need to be unique, but you should have a numeric identifier to enforce uniquenes.

Comment: There are many things here that are not good. The text datatype has been deprecated for well over a decade now. And even if it wasn't that is the wrong datatype for an address. You need to separate the pieces of an address not slam it all together (which causes you to use a string splitter to get it back apart). Gender should be char(1). Or if you are using the more current extended gender values a lookup table with a tinyint as a foreign key would be better. Not sure why you made the identity seed so huge for student? You are going to run out with that unless you switch to big int.

Comment: Is this a school project or something in the real world? I ask because if it is for school you can deal with less than great designs but in the real world you need to be more precise.

Comment: @Sean Lange Yes, it is school project, lol. I'm sorry, me too really confused with the dictionary, but I just follow them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue you faced is because your data structure was less than ideal. It did things like prevent you from changing somebody's name. I tossed together a quick example of a cleaner design. There are many assumptions here. I assumed that people have both a first and last name. I would be remiss if I didn't at least point out that assumption is not something you can always make. https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ But for a school project it is more than sufficient. I also made the assumption that the addresses are US addresses. Again, this would not work in many real world scenarios. And the last assumption is that everybody can be either Male or Female. In the world today this is not always the case but demonstrates the technique well enough.

Here is how I would probably do this type of design. I would suggest you not just blindly copy this but use it as an idea to get your design more properly normalized.

```
create table Users
(
    UserID int identity not null
    , FirstName varchar(50) not null
    , LastName varchar(50) not null
    , AddressLine1 varchar(50)
    , AddressLine2 varchar(50)
    , City varchar(50)
    , ST char(2)
    , ZipCode varchar(9)
    , Gender char(1)
    , constraint PK_Users primary key clustered
        (
            UserID
        )
    , constraint CHK_Users_Gender
        CHECK (Gender in ('M', 'F'))
    , constraint CHK_Users_ZipCode
        CHECK (LEN(ZipCode) in (5,9)) --This ensures you have either the 5 or 9 digiti zip code
)


create table Student
(
    StudentID int identity not null
    , UserID int not null
    , BirthDate date
    , constraint PK_Student primary key clustered
        (
            StudentID
        )
    , constraint FK_Student_Users foreign key (UserID) references Users(UserID)
)

create table Teacher
(
    TeacherID int identity not null
    , constraint PK_Teacher primary key clustered
        (
            TeacherID
        )
    , constraint FK_Teacher_Users foreign key (TeacherID) references Users(UserID)
)
```